# How to position a button within a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a problem positioning a button within cell.

Clicking the button runs this subroutine:

```
Public Sub TableDisplayButton()
    Dim cr As Range, cr2 As Range
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
        Set cr = .TopLeftCell
        Set cr2 = .BottomRightCell
        MsgBox cr.Address & " " & cr.Left
        .Left = cr.Left
        .Top = cr.Top
        .Width = Range(cr, cr2).Width
        .Height = Range(cr, cr2).Height
    end with
end sub
```

The button is slightly shifted left to neighbouring left cell and upon clicking it again it will reposition to another cell.

`cr.address` displays the correct cell.

Is it possible that `.left` and `.top` rounds decimal places to integer value?

Comment: It appears that `.Width` and `.Height` mess up positioning of the button. Even if I write absolute value to .Width it will shift the button.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub AlignByCell()
    Dim btn As Button
    With Range("A1")
        Set btn = Sheet1.Buttons.Add(Left:=.Left, Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, Height:=.Height)
    End With
End Sub
```